# getting run time error when un-protecting the selected range

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

here i have getting run time error when i am un-protecting selected range by (UnProtectRange)-VBA and selected range is not unprotected

i have used (ProtectRange)-VBA Macro to protect range by inputbox and the selected range has been protected by given password by another inputbox

when i am trying to unprotect range by (UnProtectRange)-VBA Macro then i have getting run-time error

```
Sub ProtectRange()
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim pws As String
  Dim ps As Variant
  pws = "123"
  Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select The Range to Protect:", "Protect", Type:=8)
  ps = InputBox("Enter Password to Protect")
  Cells.Locked = False
  rng.Locked = True
  ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=pws
  MsgBox ("Range " & "(" & rng.Address & ")" & " Locked")
End Sub



Sub UnProtectRange()
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim pws As String
  Dim ps As Variant
  pws = "123"
  Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select The Range to UnProtect:", "UnProtect", Type:=8)
  ps = InputBox("Enter Password to UnProtect")
  Cells.Locked = False
  rng.Locked = True
  ActiveSheet.UnProtect Password:=pws
  MsgBox ("Range " & "(" & rng.Address & ")" & " Un-Locked")
End Sub
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is one allowed to unlock cells and ranges while the sheet is in the protected state? i.e. should you be reversing the order of `cells.locked` `rng.locked` and `Unprotect`

Comment: Thank you so much @Yorik Your's comment has helped me to Unprotect range

Comment: go ahead and make an answer about how you fixed it. it is OK to accept your own answer

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

```
Sub UnProtectRange()
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim pws As String
  Dim ps As Variant
  pws = "123"
  Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select The Range to UnProtect:", "UnProtect", Type:=8)
  ps = InputBox("Enter Password to UnProtect")
  ActiveSheet.UnProtect Password:=pws
  Cells.Locked = False
  rng.Locked = True
  MsgBox ("Range " & "(" & rng.Address & ")" & " Un-Locked")
End Sub
```